# Pandas calculate percent from two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
A   B   C   D           
X   Y   1.0 49.453125
        2.0 67.767857
        3.0 48.770833
        4.0 43.583333


A   E   F   G   C   H
X   Z   1.0 807 1.0 34.375000
        2.0 808 1.0 35.375000
        1.0 909 2.0 1.750000
        2.0 910 2.0 48.750000
```

Now I would like to calculate the relative percentage of column H in data frame 2 with the corresponding value of column D data frame 1 if column C of both data frames are identical:

```
34.375000 * 100 / 49.453125 = 69.51
35.375000 * 100 / 49.453125 = 71.53
 1.750000 * 100 / 67.767857 = 2.58
48.750000 * 100 / 67.767857 = 71.94
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) if all values of `df2['C']` exist in `df1['C']` and then multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) and divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
mapping = df1.set_index('C')['D']
s = df2['H'].mul(100).div(df2['C'].map(mapping))
print (s)
0    69.510269
1    71.532385
2     2.582345
3    71.936759
dtype: float64
```

Another solution is use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with inner join for new `DataFrame`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='C')
s = df['H'].mul(100).div(df['D'])
print (s)
0    69.510269
1    71.532385
2     2.582345
3    71.936759
dtype: float64
```

Comment: What if the two data frames aren't identical. Is there a way to catch the error without interrupting it?